# prevent ggplot2 from dropping x axis levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualise some data where no data is informative and hence I don't want ggplot2 to drop unused x axis positions.

I have tried the following code and included some dummy data:

```
lease   <-c(1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3)
year<-c(2017,   2017,   2017,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018)
variable<-c(NA, 1,  1,  NA, 1,  1,  NA, 1,  1)
location<-  c('in', 'in',   'in',   'in',   'in',   'in',   'out',  'out',  'out')

dft<-data.frame(lease, year, variable, location)
dft%>%
mutate_all(as.character)%>%
filter(!is.na(variable))%>%
ggplot(aes(x=lease, fill = variable)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'Count', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(location~year) + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Level"))+ 
scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

which gives a plot where lease '1' is dropped on the x axis but I want to be able to include lease '1' as it is significant that it did not record data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option provides the `drop` argument from `facet_grid`.

```
dft %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  # filter(!is.na(variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lease, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'Count', position = 'stack') + 
  facet_grid(location ~ year, drop = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Level")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("", 2, 3)) +      # change labels
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())         # remove axis ticks
```

[image]

---

If we want to show empty space where there are `NA`s we can convert `lease` to a factor and do

```
dft %>%
  mutate(lease = factor(lease)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lease, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'count') + 
  facet_grid(location ~ year) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Level")) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The variable value is always NA for the corresponding level 1. That is why ggplot is dropping the value of x. With value zero, ggplot does not drop the value of x

```
lease   <-c(1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3)
year<-c(2017,   2017,   2017,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018,   2018)
variable<-c(0, 1,  1,  0, 1,  1,  0, 1,  1)
location<-  c('in', 'in',   'in',   'in',   'in',   'in',   'out',  'out',  'out')

dft<-data.frame(lease, year, variable, location)
dft%>%
  mutate_all(as.character)%>%
  filter(!is.na(variable))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(lease), fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'Count', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(location~year) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Level"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks guys @markus. Is there any way to leave that lease 1 position blank i.e. not include '0' or 'NA'?